# How to set date range maximum 1 year and not more than current date in react-datepicker

Tags: reactjs, datepicker, react-datepicker

How can we set date range maximum 1 year and not more than current date in react-datepicker.
I am using [react-datepicker](https://reactdatepicker.com/)

I try to use `maxDate={addYears(new Date(date.start_at), 1)}` in end date, It restrict user to user to maximum 1 year but allows user to choose future dates. Need help in this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
const currentDate = new Date(); // Get the current date

const maxDate = new Date(); // Create a new date object
maxDate.setFullYear(currentDate.getFullYear() + 1); // Set the maximum date to 1 year from the current date

  return (
    <DatePicker
      maxDate={maxDate}
    />
  );
```

Comment: But user should not be able to select future dates. https://prnt.sc/u7Y5VQvCrOSC